# Deal with wpf ComboBox ItemsSource changing upon selection

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a wpf user interface in which I use ComboBox to set a property to a value. The ItemsSource of the ComboBox has a Binding to a list of allowed values. I have made it so that this list is the list of allowed values but with the value currently selected removed from it. This way the list only contains values that one can actually change to. When the list is empty, I have a trigger that makes the combobox inactive.

This is all working well in terms of expected behaviour. However visually I have multiple red borders showing validation errors due to the fact the selectedvalue is no longer in the itemssource list upon update. There is no red border when I do not remove the currently SelectedValue from ItemsSource upon update.

Is there a way to get around this, maybe another Control I could use, or maybe somehow validate the SelectedValue from another list (that would contain the current value) compared to the one in ItemsSource ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't actually select a value that is not in the `ItemsSource`. What you can do is to remove the red border that shows up when there is a validation error by setting the `Validation.ErrorTemplate` attached property to an empty `ControlTemplate`:

```
<ComboBox ...>
    <Validation.ErrorTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate/>
    </Validation.ErrorTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: I understand. Is there another element I could use that would allow me to pick from a list, in a way to decouple validation ?

Comment: No. There is no such built-in control.